# Migrading from PHP4 TO PHP5

Tags: php, report

The code you see is from an app that generates a a drop-down list. You select from the drop down list and it generates a report. I am migrating this app from an old version of php to  the latest, but I cant get the list to generate on the form. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what needs to change. I am not a PHP developer, I am learning, but I am not there yet.

```
function getcourses(){
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM courses"; 



$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$course_id = $row['course_id'];
$course_no = $row['course_no'];
$course_name = $row['course_name'];
$start_month = $row['start_month'];
$start_day = $row['start_day'];
$start_year = $row['start_year'];
$end_month = $row['end_month'];
$end_day = $row['end_day'];
$end_year = $row['end_year'];

$course_date = $start_month . " " .  $start_day . ", " . $start_year . " - " . $end_month . " " .  $end_day . ", " . $end_year;

echo '<option value="' . $course_id . '~' . $course_date . '">' . $course_name . ', ' .  $course_date . '</option>';
}
}

?>
<p>Please select the course roster you would like to download from the list below</p>
<form action="download_excel.php" name="reportrequest" method="POST">
<select name="course_report">
<?php getcourses() ?>
</select>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Retrieve Report" />
</form>
```

---

So here is what the new code looks like, I still keep getting this error:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

this happens on thi line: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

```
function connect(){
$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
return $dbc;
}

function getcourses(){
$query = "SELECT FROM courses";  
$result = mysqli_query(connect(),$query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$course_id = $row['course_id'];
$course_no = $row['course_no'];
$course_name = $row['course_name'];
$start_month = $row['start_month'];
$start_day = $row['start_day'];
$start_year = $row['start_year'];
$end_month = $row['end_month'];
$end_day = $row['end_day'];
$end_year = $row['end_year'];

$course_date = $start_month . " " .  $start_day . ", " . $start_year . " - " . $end_month . " " .  $end_day . ", " . $end_year;

echo '<option value="' . $course_id . '~' . $course_date . '">' . $course_name . ', ' . $course_date . '</option>';
}

}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: You can't mix and match mysql_* and mysqli_* functions.

Comment: This is one of the errors I get:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in. Also keeps saying the $dbc is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

You're using `$dbc` even though it is not defined and/or available to your function. If it is actually defined you need to pass it as a parameter to your function so it is then available to the code within it:

```
function getcourses($dbc){
```

**Problem 2**

You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: I made the change and I still don't see the result on the drop-down. Looks like its not putting the result in the form.

Comment: I am still getting this error: PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in.           

here is the line of code that its happens to: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: Something is causing your query to fail. Unfortunately I can't troubleshoot that from here. See what mysqli_eror() tells you.

Answer (score 0):

it is better if the connection is also using a function.

like :

```
function coonect() {
$con = mysqli_connect(host,user,pass,db);
return $con;
}
```

using :

```
function getcourses(){
...
$result = mysqli_query(coonect(),$query);
...
}
```

sorry for my english